How to enforce E2E tests before github release action
I'd like to implement a conditional E2E test that needs to pass before a release is executed in production.
Currently our workflow is as follows:

A user commits a change to a branch
A PR is created, tested, merged to master.
A release is queued to staging automatically
A Cypress E2E test is executed, to test the results in staging.
The user manually releases to production.

Between steps 4 and 5, I'd like a quality gate established where if 4 fails, the user cannot run 5.
How can I achieve this?
Heres the current pipeline with a few remitted lines of cicd.
name: CI
on:
    pull_request:
        types:
            - opened
            - reopened
            - synchronize
    push:
        branches:
            - master
permissions:
    checks: write
    pull-requests: write
    contents: write
    actions: write

env:
    NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.remitted}}

defaults:
    run:
        working-directory: ./vendor

jobs:
    install:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            -   name: Checkout
                uses: actions/checkout@v4
            -   uses: remitted@master
    build:
        needs: [install]
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            -   name: Checkout
                uses: actions/checkout@v4
            -   uses: remitted/pnpm@master
            -   name: Build and then install necessary packages
                run: npm run build:uikit:production
            -   name: Build webpack
                run: NODE_ENV=development npm run build:webpack

    unit_test:
        needs: [install]
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            -   name: Checkout
                uses: actions/checkout@v4
            -   name: Create env file
                run: |
            -   uses: remitted/pnpm@master
            -   name: Test Unit
                run: npm run test:ci:coverage
    lint:
        if: ${{ github.actor != 'dependabot[bot]' }}
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        needs: [install]
        steps:
            -   name: Checkout
                uses: actions/checkout@v4
            -   uses: remitted/pnpm@master
            -   name: Lint
                run: npm run lint

    deploy_ecs:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' }}
      needs: [build, unit_test, lint]
      env:
        GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
      steps:
        - name: Checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v4
        - name: Trigger Deploy ECS
          run: gh workflow run deploy_ecs.yml --ref master

Inside deploy_ecs.yml, the deployment occurs, and the E2E is triggered like so:
trigger_e2e:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
        GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Trigger E2E
        run: gh workflow run cypress.yml --ref master

Below is the workflow that allows a user to manually release.
name: Release ECS
on:
  workflow_dispatch: 
jobs:


Can you share your current workflow yaml?

Included. Thanks @ShaykiAbramczyk

Why it 3 different pipelines and not one?

It's in an enterprise setting, we reuse a lot of the pipelines/workflows across different repos

The other reason is deploy_ecs is deployed manually for production release.

so a user can trigger a release prod workflow and you want he won't be able to that if the cypress failed. but which cypress ? of which workflow? I guess many cypress running each day. if the release prod workflow is independent how can he know what to check? (you can add a first step there to check the cypress workflow, but of which run? the latest?)

To still allow manual triggering of the workflow but also automatically run your Release ECS workflow against master when the trigger_e2e workflow has been reported successful, you could use a solution like this:
name: Release ECS
on:
  workflow_dispatch: 
  workflow_run:
    workflows: 
      - trigger_e2e
    types:
      - completed
    branches: 
      - master

jobs:
  deploy-to-prod: 
    # only runs when triggered manually OR when all of the previus workflows from `workflow_run` were successful
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' || ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }} 
    steps:
      #...

The above code assumes that you want to automically do a release when someone is running the cypress e2e test through the trigger_e2e.
If you want to always enforce the e2e tests to run, or all the other workflows, you should be able to remove the check for github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch'.
There is another way to read your question. At least from the question in the title, it sounds like you want to ensure the e2e tests run successfully when someone triggers the Release workflow manually. In this case, you could try something like this:
name: Release ECS
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  trigger-e2e:
    steps:
      - name: Trigger E2E
      - uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy_ecs.yml
  deploy-to-prod: 
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }} 
    steps:
      #...

Relevant docs:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#example-caller-workflow
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-an-action-in-the-same-repository-as-the-workflow

Please let me know if this helps :)

Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!!

So happy to help :) Thank you for the bounty, too! If you have any further questions while implementing this, please do let me know because I love these kind of problems and your question was written quite well so I am pretty confident I could answer future ones, too.
